# How to access individual pages in wordpress

Tags: ftp, wordpress, backup, restore

I have installed wordpress on my website and it's working fine (so I downloaded it, extracted it in the ftp-server of my page, and initialized a database).

I'm doing this because I want to be able to backup everything in one-click. The plan was to copy the wordpress folder back to my computer in order to do a backup, but I can't find the individual pages I have in my Blog.

The question is: where do those page lie? And how can I reach them? Are there better techniques for backing up stuff from wordpress completely?

Answer (score 1):

Your wordpress pages are stored in database. If you want to backup your wordpress installation, you will have to backup your FTP files AND your database.

Have a look at [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for more information on Wordpress database structure.

Note you can also use plugins such as [BackUpWordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/) or other ones listed [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=backup&sort=) to do this automatically.

Comment: Those backup systems are good, but I need systems that can backup and restore; not only backup! Can you help me with that?

Comment: Have a look at [Wordpress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=backup+restore) for this. It seems, there are many plugins that suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The Quantum Physicist

The page not come with the folders it is related to database you have These options list depends upon you what you want to follow :

1- copy the html code from admin panel and paste.

2- take backup of database

3- take the backup of `wp_posts` table from database.

4- you can use a plugin for that  `http://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/` or `http://wordpress.org/plugins/myrepono-wordpress-backup-plugin/`

I am trying to solve your problem
hope this helps

Thanks

Anand

Comment: Those backup systems are good, but I need systems that can backup and restore; not only backup! Can you help me with that?